# Bypass Download warning of IE 10 or click on the save button using selenium webdriver (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We want to click on save button (using selenium - web driver (c#))on this IE 10 warning message, this warning comes when we try to download any file from IE 10.

If click is not possible then please tell us how to disable this warning without changing system registry, so it should start downloading without any warning.

Comment: See this blog - http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157

Answer (score 0):

As Selenium is meant for Web and these pop ups are windows pop .....u can use either Robot class or AutiIt tool.