# Selenium: download file in Internet Explorer to specified folder without direct link, without Windows Forms, without AutoIt or Robot

Tags: java, c#, selenium, internet-explorer, download

I've often faced an issue, how to download files in IE.
In contrast to Chrome of Firefox, you cannot just specify required folder, and all the files will be downloaded to that folder. You also need to interact with native Windows forms and so on.

There are multiple options, like using AutoIt, using keyboard commands, Robot and etc... But all this options aren't stable, they require explicit waiting, using redundant libraries, and non-appropriate when run tests in parallel. The other problem, is what to do, if the file isn't downloaded by direct link, but link is generated from javascript command or received from server, and cannot be extracted from html.

All these problems can be solved, here in hte answer i'll show how to do it.
Solution is written in c#, i believe the same can be implemented in java

Comment: Downloading the file if href is not present:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66791460/7666582

Answer (score 0):

Method DownloadFileIexplore will download file to the specified filePath (folder + filename), e.g. DownloadFileExplore("C:\my_folder\report.xslx")

```
    public void DownloadFileIexplore(string filePath)
    {
        //Click the link.
        //Simple click can be used instead, but in my case it didn't work for all the links, so i've replaced it with click via action: 
        new Actions(Browser.Driver).MoveToElement(Element).Click(Element).Perform();

        //Different types of element can be used to download file.
        //If the element contains direct link, it can be extracter from 'href' attribute.
        //If the element doesn't contains href or it's just an javascript command, link will be extracted from the browser http requests.
        //
        string downloadUrlOrLink = Element.GetAttribute("href") != null && !Element.GetAttribute("href").Contains("javascript")
            ? Element.GetAttribute("href")
            : GetRequestUrls().Last() ?? GetLinkInNewWindowIexplore();
        if (downloadUrlOrLink == null)
        {
            throw Log.Exception("Download url cannot be read from the element href attribute and from the recent http requests.");
        }

        /// the last step is to download file using CookieWebClient
        /// method DownloadFile is available in the System.Net.WebClient, 
        /// but we have to create new class CookieWebClient, that will be inherited from System.Net.WebClient with one overriden method
        new CookieWebClient(GetCookies()).DownloadFile(downloadUrlOrLink, filePath);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// this method returns all the http requests sent from browser.
    /// the latest requests was send when link (or button) was clicked to download file
    /// so we will need just to get last element from list: GetRequestUrls().Last().
    /// or, if the request for file downloading isn't the last, find the required request by part of url, in my case it was 'common/handler', e.g.:
    /// GetRequestUrls().LastOrDefault(x => x.Contains("common/handler")) 
    /// <summary>
    public List<string> GetRequestUrls()
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<object> requestsUrls = (ReadOnlyCollection<object>) 
            Driver.ExecuteScript("return window.performance.getEntries().map(function(x) { return x.name });");
        return requestsUrls.Select(x => (string) x).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In some cases after clicking the Download button new window is opened in IE.
    /// Driver.WindowHandles can return only one window instead of two.
    /// To solve this problem reset IE security settings and set Enable Protected Mode for each zone.
    /// </summary>
    private string GetLinkInNewWindowIexplore()
    {
        /// here it would be better to add waiting till new window is opened.
        /// in that case we have to calculate number of windows before click and send this number as argument to GetLinkInNewWindowIexplore()
        /// and wait till number will be increased by 1 
        var availableWindows = Driver.WindowHandles;
        if (availableWindows.Count > 1)
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(availableWindows[availableWindows.Count - 1]);
        }
        string url;
        try
        {
            url = Driver.Url;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            url = Driver.ExecuteScript("return document.URL;").ToString();
        }
        Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[0]);
        return url;
    }

    public System.Net.CookieContainer GetCookies()
    {
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie cookie in Driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies)
        {
            cookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie
            {
                Name = cookie.Name,
                Value = cookie.Value,
                Domain = "domain of your site, you can find, track http requests send from your site in browser dev tools, tab Network"
            });
        }
        return cookieContainer;
    }


public class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookieContainer;

    public CookieWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        _cookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    }

    /// it's necessary to override method to add cookies, because file cannot be download by non-authorized user
    /// ServerCertificateValidationCallback is set to true to avoid some possible certificate errors
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```