# How to handle download pop up for IE in selenium JAVA

Tags: selenium

Can anyone suggest, How to handle download pop up for IE in selenium JAVA?

It's giving me Open and Save tab in popup window.

I need to save the file using Selenium.

Thanks

Comment: `InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.setCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;");
        options.setCapability("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        options.setCapability("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
        options.setCapability("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        options.setCapability("browser.download.dir","e:\\SampleExcel");
     WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);`

Comment: try to launch IE with these configuration.

Comment: I want to download .zip files , is their any other IE options available for automatic download ? – priya just now

Comment: This might be useful :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157][1]